# Reverse Engineering a python mac application compiled with "freeze"

Tags: python

(Note)I have already seen this post: [Reverse Engineering program written in Python, compiled with "freeze"](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5860/reverse-engineering-program-written-in-python-compiled-with-freeze)

Would anyone know how to do what is done in the link above using the PyCommand but with a mac app? The program I am trying to reverse engineer is compiled using the exact same program but the binary is a mac application.

Unfortunately Immunity Debugger is only able to be run on windows, so I cannot use the PyCommand (to my knowledge). Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The answer on the page to which you linked gives the exact steps necessary to dump the module. Just replace "Ollydbg" in Step 1 with "gdb" or similar.

Comment: Would I have to do that for each module? There are over 2,000 modules in the program I am wanting to decompile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [linked post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5860/reverse-engineering-program-written-in-python-compiled-with-freeze) you can use any debugger to dump frozen modules compiled with freeze. However since you are on a mac, PyCommand and Immunity Debugger will not work. However that does not prevent you from working your ways in.

On a non Windows OS, you can use [*frida*](http://www.frida.re/) to inject your code inside the running executable. <strike>Since frida injects *javascript* inside the process, you need to translate the *python* code to *js*.</strike>

You only need to dump relevant frozen modules, and it would happen automatically as `_frozen` is an array of all frozen modules.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a script to dump frozen modules using the [python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frida) for frida. The script is fairly portable and should work on all OS. You only need to provide the [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of the relevant process which you can get from *Activity Monitor* / *System Monitor* / *Task Manager* for your OS.

```
import frida, struct, sys

# Magic value of pyc files, The value provided here is for python 2.7
# You can get it by imp.get_magic()
PYTHONMAGIC = '\x03\xF3\x0D\x0A' + '\x00' * 4

# Provide the pid of your process
PID = 2008

# The size of a pointer is 8 bytes on 64 bit OS and 4 on a 32 bit OS
ptr_size = 8 if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else 4

# Name of python shared library
if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    lib_name = 'libpython2.7.so'
elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    lib_name = 'libpython2.7.dylib'
elif sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
    lib_name = 'python27.dll'
else:
    raise Exception('Unsupported platform')


session = frida.attach(PID)
export_va = 0

# Read a null terminated C string or a char array of a given length
def readString(addr, size = 0):
    if size > 0:
        return struct.unpack('@{}s'.format(size) , session.read_bytes(addr, size))[0]
    elif size == 0:
        s = ''
        while True:
            ch, = struct.unpack('@c', session.read_bytes(addr, 1))
            addr += 1
            if ch == '\x00':
                break
            else:
                s += ch
        return s
    else:
        return ''


modules = session.enumerate_modules()
for module in modules:
    if module.name == lib_name:
        exports = module.enumerate_exports()
        for export in exports:
            if export.name == 'PyImport_FrozenModules':
                export_va = module.base_address + export.relative_address
                break
    if export_va != 0:
        break


if export_va == 0:
    raise Exception("Could not get export address of PyImport_FrozenModules")

structAddr, = struct.unpack_from('@P', session.read_bytes(export_va , ptr_size))

while True:
    ptrToName, ptrToCode, sizeOfCode = struct.unpack_from('@PPi', session.read_bytes(structAddr, ptr_size * 2 + 4))
    structAddr += ptr_size * 2 + 4

    # The array is terminated by a structure whose members are null
    if ptrToName == 0 and ptrToCode == 0 and sizeOfCode == 0:
        break

    moduleName = readString(ptrToName)
    moduleCode = readString(ptrToCode, sizeOfCode)

    # You can change the output path here
    with open(moduleName + '.pyc', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(PYTHONMAGIC + moduleCode)

print '[*] Frozen modules dumped'
```

Comment: For some reason the script is not working. It is saying it cannot find PyImport_FrozenModules. I tried it out on the PC executable compiled with freeze and got the same error.

Here is a download for the binary on the mac, could you try it and see if it works for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7qpgm1hnwk5j9j/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: Update: I was able to get the script working on the PC. The issue is with the lib_name. On the mac the python dylib is embedded inside of the app itself. How would I be able to call that?

Comment: @MichaelWass The `lib_name` depends on the version of python used. For `PyImport_FrozenModules`, you need to find out which module exports it and accordingly change `lib_name`

Comment: Would it matter if it is the actual library being used or not? Or just any old lib from python 2.4?

Comment: @MichaelWass `lib_name` must be the actual library which is used by the application.