# Reverse Engineering program written in Python, compiled with “freeze 2 [REWRITE]

Tags: decompilation, python

I am already aware of the question: '[Reverse Engineering program written in Python, compiled with “freeze”](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5860/reverse-engineering-program-written-in-python-compiled-with-freeze)'

I have Immunity Debugger and is this the `pyc` code and the structures?

[image: Immunity Debugger on pyc file]

When I run the PyCommand mentioned in the original question, it doesn't dump the `pyc` code and do not make `PYC` files. And, I have the PythonMagic Code Correct (Python 2.4).

Any help?